# Page transition with CSS transform problems

Tags: javascript, css

I want to do a simple transition between two pages. The animation should be a movement from right to left to go to the second page, and then, left to right to return to the first page.

I've made this, but the problem is that duplicates the width of the page.

```js
const screen1 = document.getElementsByClassName('screen1')[0];
const screen2 = document.getElementsByClassName('screen2')[0];

document.getElementById('toggle1').addEventListener('click', () => {
  screen1.style.transform = 'translatex(-100%)';
  screen2.style.transform = 'translatex(0)';
});

document.getElementById('toggle2').addEventListener('click', () => {
  screen1.style.transform = 'translatex(0)';
  screen2.style.transform = 'translatex(100%)';
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.screen1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.screen2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translatex(100%);
  transition: transform .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="screen1">
    <button id="toggle1">Toggle</button>
  </div>
  <div class="screen2">
    <button id="toggle2">Toggle</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problems that I've with this:

- In an element with 100% of width I must to use the viewport units. In other case, the 100% will be two screens.
- An element with fixed position, positioned to the right of the screen, will take the right value of the second screen. So it won't be displayed.
- I can hide the scroll bar with `overflow-x: hidden` but the user can scroll to the next screen anytime.

There is some way to fix this problems and maintain the "slide" transition?

Comment: FYI: `document.getElementsByClassName('screen1')[0]` should be: `document.querySelector('.screen1')`. `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a live node list, which can be very inefficient, plus you aren't interested in a node list - you're looking for a single node so finding all of them is also a waste.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @ScottMarcus it's a custom that I've but I will change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `overflow: hidden` to your container.

```js
const screen1 = document.getElementsByClassName('screen1')[0];
const screen2 = document.getElementsByClassName('screen2')[0];

document.getElementById('toggle1').addEventListener('click', () => {
  screen1.style.transform = 'translatex(-100%)';
  screen2.style.transform = 'translatex(0)';
});

document.getElementById('toggle2').addEventListener('click', () => {
  screen1.style.transform = 'translatex(0)';
  screen2.style.transform = 'translatex(100%)';
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.screen1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.screen2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translatex(100%);
  transition: transform .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="screen1">
    <button id="toggle1">Toggle</button>
  </div>
  <div class="screen2">
    <button id="toggle2">Toggle</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, just didn't worked in my project. The first time I did a test without a container (just only establishing the `overflow` property in each screen). Then I just didn't test the `overflow` property with a container. I will check in my project what is happening because adding a container with `overflow`, hides all the divs with `position: absolute` inside the container. But this is the correct way.

Comment: Well I fixed that in my project, in the snippet I used top/left/right bottom properties. In my project I was using only width 100%, causing that the absolute elements in container were hidden. If you don't use `overflow` you can see that elements, but if you use it, the elements disappears.

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow:hidden` property to your `.container`